# Why do I get the error "undefined method 'merge' for true:TrueCLass" when adding a checkbox in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, scaffolding

I am very new to development and was hoping someone could assist:

I receive the error "undefined method 'merge' error when I include the following checkbox:

```
<%= f.check_box :is_female, true %> <%= f.label :is_female, "Female" %>    
<%= f.check_box :is_female, false %> <%= f.label :is_female, "Male" %>
```

The above code is in the profiles folder which I created using the following:

```
$ rails generate scaffold profiles description:string
```

I then generated the following migration:

```
$ rails generate migration add_websites_to_profiles website:string
```

This created the migrate file `*************_add_website_to_profiles.rb`

Here is the add_websites_to_profiles.rb:

```
class AddWebsiteToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change


  add_column :profiles, :website, :string
  add_column :profiles, :is_female, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

I manually added the following:

```
add_column :profiles, :is_female, :boolean, default: false
```

I receive the error when I have the `true` and `false` command in the checkbox. When I remove `true` `false` it appears on the page with no error, but it is not saved to db.

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: Change it to `f.check_box :is_female, {}, true`

Comment: For boolean fields, its better to use radio buttons

Comment: Thank you all! I will try this when I have a chance an let you all know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting mixed up between two ways of generating a check box I think.

The form builder version, [`f.check_box`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box), you are using expects a hash as the second parameter. You'd need to call `f.check_box(:is_female, {}, true)` for a value of `true`.

[`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) on the other hand does expect a value as the second parameter. You could use `check_box_tag(:is_female, true)` instead.

However, as @Santosh points out in the comments, you'd probably be better off having a pair of radio buttons if you want the object to be either male or female.